# how can scrapy avoid rel=nofollow, it caused return nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, xpath, scrapy

python3.6

there two price tag one is have rel=nofollow which casued same result output.:

```
 1.<span class="price" id="product-price-013">
                            $0.50                </span>

 2.   <div class="price-box" rel="nofollow">
     <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-01">
                                <span class="price">$76</span>                </span>                              
 3. name html <div class="oh h89"><a href="https://example.com/11.html" title="11">11</a></div>
```

my code:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    for detail in response.xpath("//div[@class='oh h89']"):
        item = exampleItem()
        item['name'] = detail.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()  #got different.i have tried add**//** in **//a**. it also caused same result.
        item['price'] = str((detail.xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'product-price-')]")).xpath('string(.)').extract()[0]).strip()  #got same result. i can't delete **//**, because there are **rel=nofollow** in the middle.
        yield item
```

edit:

this will result different name but same price.
in my computer, it look like this:

```
31157P00, Version B
$75.99
30981P00, Version A
$75.99
710-050100-049
$75.99
8 Keys, B Stock
$75.99
```

i want get different result.
i have tried two days for this, i think i'm confused. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `//` in your this XPATH `//span[starts-with(@id, 'product-price-')]` that means search from entire document.

change it to `span[starts-with(@id, 'product-price-')]` which will search relatively.

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    for detail in response.xpath("//div[@class='oh h89']"):
        item = exampleItem()
        item['name'] = detail.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()  #got different result.
        item['price'] = str((detail.xpath("span[starts-with(@id, 'product-price-')]")).xpath('string(.)').extract()[0]).strip()  #got same result
        yield item
```

PS:

I dont know how `detail.xpath("a/text()")[0].extract()` is working, I think it should be `detail.xpath("a/text()").extract()[0]` OR `detail.xpath("a/text()").extract_first()`

Comment: thanks for so quickly answer my question.  i can't change **//span** to **span**.  because there are have a class **<div class="price-box" rel="nofollow">** in the middle. if i must change, it will look like this:**detail.xpath("div[@class='price-box']/span[starts-with(@id, 'product-price-')]/span[@class='price']/text()")[0].extract()**  but it also doesn't work, because there are have a **rel=nofollow**. it will return nothing. thanks again.

Comment: Sorry but your question seems unclear, please post your current code's output, and also the expected output, please edit your question and tell me